# ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing

Tags: python, py2exe

I programmed a python application (used wxPython; py2exe; python 2.6).

Now my code is using the multiprocessing module. It works! (IDE)

When I try to build this code I got no problems.
But when I execute this built .exe file I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "myprogram.py", line 800, in
>   
>       multiprocessing.freeze_support()    File "multiprocessing__init__.pyc", line 100, in freeze_support
>
> File "multiprocessing\forking.pyc", line 153, in 
>   ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing

The _multiprocessing.pyd is available. I checked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the line **freeze_support()** after your main code.... Here is the main link to the docs [multiprocessing freeze support](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support)

Also these 2 questions mention the same thing [stackoverflow ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048651/problem-deploying-python-program-packaged-with-py2exe) and [multiprocessing and pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073942/multiprocessing-problem-pyqt-py2exe)

Do tell if it works for you...........

Comment: From the backtrace it looks like he's calling freeze_support.